# Is this bad for performance?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example:

Order of the rules.

```
.div-3 {float:right}
.div-4 {width:100%}
.div-2 {width:50%}
#div-1 {width:30%}
```

Do browsers care?

```
<div id="div-1"></div>

<div class="div-2"></div>

<div class="div-3"></div>

<div class="div-4"></div>
```

Keep the original.

Comment: Uh...no, I don't think this should be one of your considerations when trying to improve CSS efficiency. Read some of the guides out there for more useful ideas on how to do that, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Comment: Do you mean if the order of CSS rulesets affects performance? I don't understand what makes you think your example could have bad performance.

Comment: ya @Oriol......

Comment: In this specific example no, the order makes no difference. However there are often multiple CSS rules that can be applied to the same element, in which case the order can matter based on the specificity. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: What kills CSS performance are advanced rendering techniques (especially semi-opacity), fixed background images (as it prevents a number of scrolling optimizations), and text-heavy websites that perform layout based on the text flow. The syntactic arrangement of rules doesn't even register in comparison.

Comment: Assuming a strictly valid HTML document, it should make no difference. There are many ways a stylesheet can delay the response, but this is not it. For optimization, you can harvest 99% of the results with caching, compressing, minimizing css, removing unneccessary rules, refactoring overqualified selectors to decrease file size, and using less animation/transition magic which would require rendering resources.

Answer (score 2):

No, the order of CSS rulesets should not affect performance.

Browsers can't assume things like that each selector will only match one element, which will follow the element matched by the previous selector.

Browsers first load all the CSS, and then, for each element, they search which selectors match it. All selectors which could potentially match it are checked, independently on their order in the stylesheet. Otherwise the styles wouldn't apply.

Basically the order of CSS declarations only matters because when there is a draw in specificity and importance, the latest will win the cascade.